# Matplotlib Python Valores en eje X

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, pls

Con el siguiente codigo quiero que me muestre un par de cosas mas. Quiero que me muestre en el eje x del 0 al 23 que son la cantidad de datos por dia que hay y solo me muestra ahora 0,5,10,15 y 20. Por otro lado quiero que en cada valor por ejemplo en Monday 6492 me lo marque en la recta con un punto.
Ademas quisiera poder dimensionar el tamaño de mi ventana, hacerla mas ancha y que en cada linea del grafico me muestre el nombre de la funcion ejemplo(Monday linea roja)
Gracias

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Last Week
Monday = plt.plot([6492,5199,4738,5184,4079,4081,4165,4866,4294,5203,7467,6661,5135,4472,5527,6190,5059,4438,4603,10548,7895,7457,6943,6829])
Tuesday = plt.plot([6410,5372,4852,5244,3795,4340,4725,4921,5508,4818,5212,4536,3936,3785,3780,5933,5673,7303,8000,9325,9349,7996,7871,5710])
Wednesday = plt.plot([6143,5443,4914,4592,4862,5667,7371,9304,7390,11598,9454,7619,8871,7499,9651,9970,12896,12007,12531,12907,12581,11708,11812,10167])
Thursday = plt.plot([6287,6225,5794,5247,5719,7945,14252,11354,8978,11466,11983,10625,12951,10409,4545,3849,3734,3228,3291,3939,3429,2933,3462,2580])
Friday = plt.plot([1975,1407,1187,1494,1680,1682,1845,3871,3758,3622,5147,5421,4691,4909,4001,3866,3532,2522,1678,4698,3316,2120,2054,2387])
Saturday = plt.plot([1893,1873,2038,1551,1717,1919,1899,2608,3460,3757,3697,4491,4182,4271,3386,2937,3272,2361,1800,2647,1839,1921,2854,2060])
Sunday = plt.plot([1497,966,1235,1650,1360,1834,1377,2223,7014,3346,4075,4835,14237,4528,2119,2031,2189,2099,3501,13374,2173,3173,9402,5425])

plt.ylabel('impressions')
plt.xlabel('hours')
plt.show()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para añadirle los puntos en cada valor solo debes usar "-o", con `-` le indicamos que una los valores con lineas, y con el 'o' le indicamos que en cada valor coloque un punto.

Si deseas que se muestre las etiquetas del eje X debes usar plt.xticks()

En tu caso:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Monday = plt.plot([6492,5199,4738,5184,4079,4081,4165,4866,4294,5203,7467,6661,5135,4472,5527,6190,5059,4438,4603,10548,7895,7457,6943,6829], "-o")
Tuesday = plt.plot([6410,5372,4852,5244,3795,4340,4725,4921,5508,4818,5212,4536,3936,3785,3780,5933,5673,7303,8000,9325,9349,7996,7871,5710], "-o")
Wednesday = plt.plot([6143,5443,4914,4592,4862,5667,7371,9304,7390,11598,9454,7619,8871,7499,9651,9970,12896,12007,12531,12907,12581,11708,11812,10167], "-o")
Thursday = plt.plot([6287,6225,5794,5247,5719,7945,14252,11354,8978,11466,11983,10625,12951,10409,4545,3849,3734,3228,3291,3939,3429,2933,3462,2580], "-o")
Friday = plt.plot([1975,1407,1187,1494,1680,1682,1845,3871,3758,3622,5147,5421,4691,4909,4001,3866,3532,2522,1678,4698,3316,2120,2054,2387], "-o")
Saturday = plt.plot([1893,1873,2038,1551,1717,1919,1899,2608,3460,3757,3697,4491,4182,4271,3386,2937,3272,2361,1800,2647,1839,1921,2854,2060], "-o")
Sunday = plt.plot([1497,966,1235,1650,1360,1834,1377,2223,7014,3346,4075,4835,14237,4528,2119,2031,2189,2099,3501,13374,2173,3173,9402,5425], "-o")
plt.xticks([i for i in range(24)]) 
plt.ylabel('impressions')
plt.xlabel('hours')
plt.show()
```

Salida:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias, sabes como agregarle el nombre de la variable a cada linea? y como hacer para que cuando me pose con el cursor arriba de cada punto me muestre el valor del eje y?

Comment: o aunque sea que me diga el nombre de cada linea con su respectivo color al costado

Comment: @MartinBouhier Quieres que se muestre una lengenda?

Comment: Si eso es lo que quieres solo añade un label: `Monday = plt.plot([...], "-o", label="Lunes")` y despues llamas a `plt.legend()`

Comment: Perfecto, solo me faltaria que cuando pase con el raton por cada punto de las lineas me dijera el valor que tiene